# Is there a way or an option to File Roller (now GNOME Archive Manager) to use a single window session?

Tags: software-recommendation, archive, file-roller

Is there a way or an option in File Roller (now GNOME Archive Manager) to use a single window session.

The default is to open a separate window for each archive you open.

Is this possible, or are there alternative archive-managers with this capability?

Answer (score 2):

It seems this isn't possible in File roller, but as an alternative (like you asked) you can use [xarchiver](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xarchiver) [image: Install xarchiver].

To install it, click on this button:

[image: Install via the software center]

It will not open a new window, rather it will open a new tab in the existing window. Here is a screenshot of the xarchiver:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will set it up as soon as the upgrade to 12.10

Comment: I was testing it but has problems opening files 7z (not open properly or crashed the program)...

Comment: You asked an alternative and i think xarchiver could be that one. Crashing can be a bug or something, but it works great here. Make sure you have `p7zip-full` package installed